# Radio buttons dropping text below radio button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.0 and am having issues with my radio buttons.

The problem is anything with long text drops the text below the radio button instead of just wrapping below the first line. On full screen on a wide screen monitor it looks fine. But as the size gets smaller it looks very bad. I thought bootstrap automatically word wraps for you.

Am I using bootstrap the wrong way?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="Valid-Driver-License" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required value="#form.FLDL#" />
            <label for="Valid-Driver-License">A valid driver license or ID card with photo issued by any US state or territory (Florida driver license must indicate a Manatee County address)</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="Canadian-Driver-License" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required value="#form.Canadian#" />
            <label for="Canadian-Driver-License">A Canadian driver license or ID card </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="Valid-Passport" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required value="#form.Passport#" />
            <label for="Valid-Passport">A valid US or out-of-country passport</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="Power-Of-Attorney-Copy" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required  value="#form.POA#" />
            <label for="Power-Of-Attorney-Copy">If transaction is being completed by <a href="https://www.powerdms.com/public/MCTC/documents/1474142" target="_blank">Power of Attorney</a> a copy of the valid driver license, identification card or passport for both the applicant <font color="red">and</font> the person appointed power of attorney is required. <font color="red">If the Power of Attorney appoints a business/dealership alone or with an individual, the business/dealership must include a letter of authorization on their letterhead stating that the person who is signing by power of attorney on their behalf is authorized to do so.</font></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is putting the `input` inside the `label` tag; this way the text will wrap and continue in a new line but the first one will always stay at the side of the input.

```css
.example-2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Valid-Driver-License">
       <input id="Valid-Driver-License" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required value="#form.FLDL#" />
      A valid driver license or ID card with photo issued by any US state or territory (Florida driver license must indicate a Manatee County address)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="Canadian-Driver-License" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required value="#form.Canadian#" />
      <label for="Canadian-Driver-License">A Canadian driver license or ID card </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="Valid-Passport" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required value="#form.Passport#" />
      <label for="Valid-Passport">A valid US or out-of-country passport</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Power-Of-Attorney-Copy">
      <input id="Power-Of-Attorney-Copy" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required value="#form.POA#" />
      If transaction is being completed by <a href="https://www.powerdms.com/public/MCTC/documents/1474142" target="_blank">Power of Attorney</a> a copy of the valid driver license, identification card or passport for both the applicant <font color="red">and</font> the person appointed power of attorney is required. <font color="red">If the Power of Attorney appoints a business/dealership alone or with an individual, the business/dealership must include a letter of authorization on their letterhead stating that the person who is signing by power of attorney on their behalf is authorized to do so.</font></label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<!-- New Example -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group example-2">
      <input id="Power-Of-Attorney-Copy" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required value="#form.POA#" />
      <label for="Power-Of-Attorney-Copy">
      If transaction is being completed by <a href="https://www.powerdms.com/public/MCTC/documents/1474142" target="_blank">Power of Attorney</a> a copy of the valid driver license, identification card or passport for both the applicant <font color="red">and</font> the person appointed power of attorney is required. <font color="red">If the Power of Attorney appoints a business/dealership alone or with an individual, the business/dealership must include a letter of authorization on their letterhead stating that the person who is signing by power of attorney on their behalf is authorized to do so.</font></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very close but the last bullet wraps underneath the radio button is it able to just wrap underneath where the first line of text begins? To have it line up nicely?

Comment: @DavidBrierton absolutely, the easiest way for that IMO is to just make the parent of both elements a flex-container, (remember to first take the `input` out of the `label`) this way you can align items in either columns or rows, check the answer again, last bullet... Now, Flexbox is really powerful, and Bootstrap v4 is all built on flexbox, so if possible I'd recommend changing from v3 to v4 :)

Comment: you took the row out when i add the row it drops the text underneath the bullet

Comment: The row doesn't matter, you can add it or remove it, what matters is that the container for the input and the label is a flex container, check again, I wrapped all inside a row, it still looks the same

Comment: @DavidBrierton were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the  tag inside the  tag.

```
<label for="Power-Of-Attorney-Copy">
    <input id="Power-Of-Attorney-Copy" name="residenceProof" type="radio" required  value="#form.POA#" />
       If transaction is being completed by <a href="https://www.powerdms.com/public/MCTC/documents/1474142" target="_blank"> Power of Attorney</a> a copy of the valid driver license, identification card or passport for both the applicant <font color="red">and</font> the person appointed power of attorney is required. <font color="red">If the Power of Attorney appoints a business/dealership alone or with an individual, the business/dealership must include a letter of authorization on their letterhead stating that the person who is signing by power of attorney on their behalf is authorized to do so.</font>
</label>
```